# Call Controller Action from script in View

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

I am trying to call the controller action from my script but the method is not being invoked.

This is my controller action:

```
 [HttpPost]    
 public ActionResult EditQuantity(int? id, int quantity)
 {
     if (id == null)
     {
          return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }
     Cart cart = db.Carts.Find(id);
     if (cart == null)
     {
         return HttpNotFound();
     }
     cart.Quantity = quantity;
     db.SaveChanges();
     string url = this.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;
     return Redirect(url);
 }
```

This is my script:

```
<script>
    function refreshTotal(ProductId) {
        var qty = document.getElementById("product-quantity-" + ProductId).value;
        var UnitPrice = document.getElementById("unit-price-" + ProductId).innerText;
        var total = qty * UnitPrice;
        document.getElementById("product-total-" + ProductId).innerHTML = "$" + total.toFixed(2);

        $.post('@Url.Action("EditQuantity", "Home")', { "id": ProductId, "quantity": qty }, function (data) {           

        });
    }
</script>
```

And the script is being called as follows from HTML:

```
<td class=""><img src="" class="img-responsive" onclick="refreshTotal(@product.Id)"></td>
```

The solution is going in the script, from the script the call is not being made to the action.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in 'productId' - should be 'ProductId'. It's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

everything seems good in your provided code. Have you looked for any javascript error in browser console and your action is in right controller ?

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I dont have as  much repute (50) to reply in comments.

Comment: Actually you don't need to answer because he solved his own problem before you post.